# avoid passing redundant parameters

Tags: kotlin

I am using Kotlin with Spring Webflux.

I have two functions which extract the some data from the request, makes the extracted data available to the upcoming function.

The example contains only two functions but I have a dozen.

```
suspend fun extractQueryParam1(serverRequest: ServerRequest,
                               fn: (p1: String) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse =
    serverRequest.queryParamOrNull("p1")
        ?.let(fn)
        ?: badRequestResponse("Missing p1")

suspend fun extractQueryParam2(serverRequest: ServerRequest,
                               fn: (p1: Long) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse =
    serverRequest.queryParamOrNull("p2")
        ?.toLong()
        ?.let(fn)
        ?: badRequestResponse("Missing p2")
```

Usage

```
    extractQueryParam1(req) { p1 ->
        extractQueryParam2(req) { p2 ->

        }
    }
```

The `req` is somehow like a context for these functions and they share the same context.

What I would like to achieve is somehow to avoid passing the `req` manually.

Is this achievable in Kotlin? How?

I inspired myself from Akka HTTP in terms of usage. They achieved this using Directives but I haven't go there... yet.

Here is an example: https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/routing-dsl/routes.html#route-seal-method-to-modify-httpresponse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make them into extension functions, and then you can use `with` or `run` scopes to call a series of these without repeatedly passing the parameter.

```
suspend fun ServerRequest.extractQueryParam1(
                               fn: (p1: String) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse =
    queryParamOrNull("p1")
        ?.let(fn)
        ?: badRequestResponse("Missing p1")

suspend fun ServerRequest.extractQueryParam2(
                               fn: (p1: Long) -> ServerResponse): ServerResponse =
    queryParamOrNull("p2")
        ?.toLong()
        ?.let(fn)
        ?: badRequestResponse("Missing p2")
```

Usage:

```
with(req) {
    extractQueryParam1 { p1 ->
        extractQueryParam2 { p2 ->

        }
    }
}
```

Since you're building a DSL, instead of `with` or `run`, you might want to write your own scope function that builds the request and then runs the code  within its lambda, using the build request as the receiver.

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more the latter option?

Comment: Maybe in your DSL, there should be an outermost element that creates the request. The higher order function that represents this element could take a lambda with Request receiver. Then when you use it, it would be similar to using `with(req)` except it would be part of your DSL. I don't know if this make sense with what you're doing as I have never used Spring.